# Cannot access key-value pair in a C++ unordered_map from a detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, singleton, unordered-map

I'm a Java developer and been writing in C++ for only a week, so go easy on me :-)

I have some code where I detach a thread and I need to use that thread to send messages to registered servers. The thread is contained within a singleton UpdateService with an unordered_map as a member variable. The problem is my key value pair is going missing after it is added to the unordered_map.

Constructor & Singleton instantiation:

```
UpdateService& UpdateService::getInstance()
{
    static UpdateService onlyInstance;
    return onlyInstance;
}

UpdateService::UpdateService() 
{
    std::thread t(&UpdateService::pollForUpdates, this);
    t.detach();
}
```

Poll for updates:

```
void UpdateService::pollForUpdates()
{
    while (true) {

        std::cout << "UpdateService 33 " << m_client_registrations.size() << "\n";

        std::unordered_map<std::string, ServerStub>::iterator iterator = m_client_registrations.begin();
        if ( iterator != m_client_registrations.end())
        {
            std::string clientId =  iterator->first;

            std::cout << "UpdateService 38 " << clientId << "\n";
            sendUpdate(clientId);
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(1));

    }

}
```

My UpdateService enables registration:

```
void UpdateService::registerForUpdates(std::string clientId, ServerStub server)
{

    if ( nullptr == getServer(clientId) ) {
        std::pair<std::string, ServerStub> pair (clientId, server);
        m_client_registrations.insert(pair);
        std::cout << "UpdateService 71 " << m_client_registrations.size() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "UpdateService 74 " << m_client_registrations.size() << "\n";
}
```

I set my objects up from a Main method like this:

```
//initialise the update service and server stub
UpdateService service = UpdateService::getInstance();
ServerStub server = ServerStub();
service.registerForUpdates("clientId0", server);
```

The console output looks like this:

```
UpdateService 33 0
--> server is being registered here
UpdateService 71 1
UpdateService 74 1
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
UpdateService 33 0
```

Please can anyone suggest to me what might be going on here? The map is a member variable and defined in my header file std::unordered_map m_client_registrations;

I would also be really interested to learn how I should debug this and work it out for myself, I have been thrown into the deep end with no C++ developers around to help me. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you running an optimized release build or an unoptimized debug one?  The optimizer could optimize your `pollForUpdates` function and only read from `m_clientRegistrations` once since there's nothing in your loop that it would see as being able to change it.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question or not, but I am building the solution with the standard IDE configuration and then choosing Local Windows Debugger --> Release. So far this has been working fine for what I have needed but I don't know the nuances between different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need locking to arbitrate access to the map and synchronise its memory afterwards.  Add a `std::mutex` member to the `UpdateService`, and ensure all threads only access the map when holding a lock thereon, as in:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_client_registrations_mutex);
    ...access or change the m_client_registrations...
} // automatic unlock happens as you leave scope
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a go. I haven't worked with threads in a very long time, although at least if the program was written in Java I'd have more confidence.

Comment: When I declare the mutex member variable I get the compiler error: error C2248: 'std::mutex::mutex' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::mutex'

Comment: Update to above: this appears to be related to the fact that UpdateService is a singleton. If I make the copy constructor private, UpdateService::getInstance(); no longer compiles, so the getInstance() must be attempting to copy the mutex.

Comment: @Petra The `UpdateService service = UpdateService::getInstance();` call is copying your instance and creating the behavior you see, since you have two instances of your singleton.  You want to use a reference variable: `UpdateService &service = UpdateService::getInstance();`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm 2 Thank you so much, this fixed my problem!